# OllyDbg "runs away" when stepping over wininet.HttpSendRequestW

Tags: ollydbg

I'm, using OllyDbg 1.1 to debug some malware and it's been quite a while since I've dealt with `wininet` calls. When I set a software or hardware breakpoint directly after the call to `wininet.HttpSendRequestW` the breakpoint never hits and it seems like the malware hangs.

I've also verified that I can reach the internet and the resource that is involved in the `HttpSendRequestW` call. What's the trick to allowing a step-over on these wininet functions?

Comment: Can you share this malware ? I want analyze why happens this.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the program calls [`InternetSetStatusCallback`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetsetstatuscallback) which allows setting a callback to be called during different stages of the connection.

Possibly the callback performs the actual work, or it detects the debugger and hangs without returning to the caller.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I worked around the issue by providing the data directly and skipping the call to `HttpSendRequest` but that's not really a good solution and doesn't help me understand why it's happening